# Determining autotransformation applied with metaMDS

Tags: vegan, mds

How do I determine the type of transformation that metaMDS is applying to my community data when `autotransform=TRUE`?

Answer (score 1):

See the help for `?metaMDS`. The Details section explains what the function is doing. In particular

> *Transformation:* If the data values are larger than common abundance class scales, the function performs a Wisconsin double standardization (`wisconsin`). If the values look very large, the function also performs sqrt transformation. Both of these standardizations are generally found to improve the results. However, the limits are completely arbitrary (at present, data maximum 50 triggers `sqrt` and 
>   9 triggers `wisconsin`). If you want to have a full control of the analysis, you should set `autotransform = FALSE` and standardize and transform data independently. The `autotransform` is intended for community data, and for other data types, you should set `autotransform = FALSE`. This step is perfomed using `metaMDSdist`.

If you look at the output printed to the screen when you run `metaMDS` right before it starts doing the random starts, it will print which transformation is used:

```
library('vegan')
data(varespec)
set.seed(1)
metaMDS(varespec)

> metaMDS(varespec)
Square root transformation
Wisconsin double standardization
Run 0 stress 0.1843196 
Run 1 stress 0.2455912 
Run 2 stress 0.2169407
....
```

Comment: My call prints no lines about transformations. Should I then assume that no transformation was automatically applied?

    '> metaMDS(zb_g_comm,distance='bray',k=3,autotransform=T,trymax=9999)
Run 0 stress 0.1328145 
Run 1 stress 0.1345457 
Run 2 stress 0.1345843 
Run 3 stress 0.1328351 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.008645817  max resid 0.04736491 
Run 4 stress 0.1328108 '

Comment: Yes I think you can assume that no transformation was applied.